# Laravel 7: How to save uploaded files into another machine/server?

Tags: filesystems, laravel-7

there!
I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to get along with the filesystem.
I need to save the uploaded files into another machine on the network.
I tried to change the config/filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'NAZ' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '192.168.254.200/FILES/', // this is the IP of another machine from the network
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

At my controller, if I call: 
`Storage::disk('NAZ')->directories();` 
I get the error: "Impossible to create the root directory \"192.168.254.200/FILES/\". "
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use FTP, so you will need to install FTP server to that machine then do things like how they are right here

```
'FTP' => [
    'driver'   => 'FTP',
    'host'     => 'ftp.example.com/ip adress',
    'username' => 'your-username',
    'password' => 'your-password',
 ]
```

remember to change the default in your `config/filesystem.php`

```
'default' => 'FTP',
```

then you can save the file to the server as usual

```
Storage::put('image.png');
```

but remember if you have not selected the `FTP` driver as default you will need to specify the drive name

```
Storage::disk('FTP')->put('image.png');
```

Comment: Is there no other way?
I have a codeigniter application on the same network that can save files on that machine without having to use the ftp protocol.
It is strange that the only option is to install ftp while another apache can do exactly the same thing with a "simpler" framework :(

Comment: from the official documentation, i have found no any other solution expect that here is the link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I needed to mount, on the laravel machine, the path to the other (my files server)

After that, my filesystem data worked as expected!